# web browser control

Tags: vb6

where do i get the  web browser control in i can not find it in my vb 6.0

Comment: You're looking for the Microsoft Internet Controls (see MSDN explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms234651(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Click on the **project** menu item, then the **components** menu item then check the **Microsoft Internet Controls** entry on the list, then click **OK**
The browser control icon (a globe) then appears in your toolbox